# Programmatically set value in material-ui Autocomplete TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield

In my React app I have an input which could take value from the dropdown list. For that putpose I use material-ui Autocomplete and TextField components.

**Question:** how can I programmaticaly set an input value by clicking on the button without choosing from the dropdown list? For example, I want to set "The Godfather" from the example and this value should be visually seen in the input.

[Codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-material-ui-od6ot)

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // set value in TextField from dropdown list
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Autocomplete
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Set value</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 }
];
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can store desired value in state and pass it to auto complete component.

Import **useState**:

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

using **useState**:

```
   const [val,setVal]=useState({})
```

changin value on click of button

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    setVal(top100Films[0]);//you pass any value from the array of top100Films
   // set value in TextField from dropdown list
 };
```

and pass this value to component in render

```
 <Autocomplete
   value={val}
    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Combo box"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth

      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: If your Autocomplete can have multiple values (attribute `multiple` is set), then the value to the `value` attribute should be an array. For the above case it would be `setVal([top100Films[0]]);` instead of `setVal(top100Films[0]);`

Comment: Passing an array does not render anything.

Comment: i did this when using mui autocomplete and formik. When i set the default value on the autocomplete, formik state is not updated to take the default selected value into its state. Any idea of how this could be done

Answer (score 8):

if you want to show the default selected value in input you must also set inputValue property and onInputChange event of the Autocompelete component

changes in state:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
```

changes in handle click

```
const handleClick = () => {
   setValue(top100Films[0]);
   setInputValue(top100Films[0]);
};
```

changes in autocompelete

```
 <Autocomplete
    {...custom}
    value={value}
    inputValue={inputValue}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
      setInputValue(newInputValue);
    }}

    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...input}
        {...params}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: Note that `value` in this example would be an array of objects, while `inputValue` should be a string: https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/ 

Thus `handleChange` should set `inputValue` using the `title` property, e.g. `setInputValue(top100Films[0].title`

Answer (score 3):

No one gives the correct answer...

```
const options = [
  { label: "A", value: 1 },
  { label: "B", value: 2 },
  { label: "A", value: 3 },
];

function MyInput() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(options[0].value);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={options.find((option) => option.value === value)}
      onChange={(_, v) => setValue(v?.value)}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params}/>
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're here trying to test a change handler that is called from MUI's `Autocomplete` component:

In your setupTests.js file

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

document.createRange = () => ({
  setStart: () => {},
  setEnd: () => {},
  commonAncestorContainer: {
    nodeName: 'BODY',
    ownerDocument: document
  }
})
```

In your test file:

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

...

const { getByRole } = render(<MyComponentWithAutocomplete />)

const autocomplete = getByRole('textbox')

// click into the component
autocomplete.focus()

// type "a"
fireEvent.change(document.activeElement, { target: { value: 'a' } })

// arrow down to first option
fireEvent.keyDown(document.activeElement, { key: 'ArrowDown' })

// select element
fireEvent.keyDown(document.activeElement, { key: 'Enter' })

expect(autocomplete.value).toEqual('Arkansas')
expect(someChangeHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

For more examples, check out the [tests in the library](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/32d647cbf72fb3661638d88c428ba37b804b6f15/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.test.js)

Answer (score 0):

when the option is not present in the dropdown it will add a new option

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const filter = createFilterOptions();

export default function FreeSoloCreateOption() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (typeof newValue === 'string') {
          
          setValue({
            title: newValue,
          });
        } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
          // Create a new value from the user input
          top100Films.push({title: newValue.inputValue})
          setValue({
            title: newValue.inputValue,
          });
        } else {
          setValue(newValue);
        
        }
       
        
      
      }}
      filterOptions={(options, params) => {
        const filtered = filter(options, params);

        const { inputValue } = params;
        // Suggest the creation of a new value
        const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.title);
        if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
          filtered.push({
            inputValue,
            title: `Add "${inputValue}"`,
          });
        }

        return filtered;
      }}
      selectOnFocus
      clearOnBlur
      handleHomeEndKeys
      id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
        // Value selected with enter, right from the input
        if (typeof option === 'string') {
          return option;
        }
        // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
        if (option.inputValue) {
          return option.inputValue;
        }
        // Regular option
        return option.title;
      }}
      renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.title}</li>}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      freeSolo
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Free solo with text demo" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 }
 
];
```